# Create shortcut key in Windows XP to a String (text)

Tags: windows, shortcuts

one of my friends asked me yesterday if there was some way for him to create a shortcut key and attached it to his E-mail addressee (thus a string or text).

Example: In a document, mail, webpage, etc. press CTRL + M (or another combination) it writes "mymail@mydomain.com"

Is this possible?

Mestika

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also highly recommend [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), [as @Snark suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/115729/create-shortcut-key-in-windows-xp-to-a-string-text/115731#115731), but I'd suggest you use a [hotstring](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) like this:

```
::my@::mymail@mydomain.com
```

If that line is in your `.ahk` script, every time you type `my@` followed by a space or a tab, it will auto-expand it into `mymail@mydomain.com`, anywhere and everywhere you type it.

No need to worry about collisions with `Ctrl-M` in other applications.

Answer (score 6):

Easy to do with **[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)**. This command will map <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> to type the email address:

```
^m::Send, mymail@mydomain.com
```

Comment: AHK is the way to go.  Considering how likely Ctrl+M is to be used you might want to limit AHK to the particular programs where this shortcut is desired.

Answer (score 1):

[ClipCache](http://www.xrayz.co.uk/clipcache/) may suite your needs